# How increase forecast accuracy in sklearn linear regression

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have this code -

```
wd_val = load_workbook(filename = 'table.xlsx')
sheet_form = wd_val['2017 год']

x = []
y = []

for a in range(6, 996):
    x.append([sheet_form['C' + str(a)].value, 
              sheet_form['D' + str(a)].value,
              sheet_form['E' + str(a)].value,
              sheet_form['F' + str(a)].value,
              sheet_form['G' + str(a)].value])

    y.append(sheet_form['H' + str(a)].value)

xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)

model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False, normalize=True)
model.fit(x, y)

#xInput - 2107, 746, 1037, 1691, 26
predict = model.predict(xInput)
#predict = 562108
```

This forecast is a little inaccurate, it should be equal to ~596.495
How i can improve prediction accuracy? Maybe you need to use a different regression model?
I train the model according to the data from the Excel table (there are more than 900 lines for training).

Comment: Linear regression is one of the simplest statistical methods. It tries to reduce the sum of squared errors in your data. Forecasting has a fair number of factors that needs to be taken care of ex: trend, seasonality which I don't think linear regression would be able to capture. I would suggest you to try some different approximator.

Comment: It's difficult to know whether that prediction is good or bad without knowing more about your dataset.  It could be that linear regression is not a sufficiently flexible model, or it could be that an error of 34,000 is already pretty good.

Comment: What other data need to be provided? This is dataset - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B807sXQwbLv22oxPDVUgi8F2SqSNEYFr